# Checking for Alerts Programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, alert, alarm, alertview

I have Scenario like,
I scheduled 2-3 alarms in my iPhone. Now I am running my app. When my app is executing, and if alarm has been triggered(or any other type of alert shown in my device), i want to know about that alert programmatically to App and do some task according to the alert i got. so, just i want to know that is there anyway by which you get to know that some alert has been displayed(may be system alert) on your screen.

Comment: did you mean you want to know that which alarm is triggered ?

Comment: no just any type of alert present on my screen, it may be system alert or alert from my app itself

Answer (score 0):

You can by : (Not tested with System Alerts)

```
- (BOOL)isALertOnScreen
{
    for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows)
    {
        NSArray* subviews = window.subviews;
        if ([subviews count] > 0)
        {
            for (id obj in subviews)
            {
                DLog(@"%@",[obj class]);
                if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
                    return YES;
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: @MDThakkar: your app should not be in background !

Comment: No, my app is in foreground, I have done the task as: scheduled alarm after 1 minute, i have button, when i press button , then i had kept sleep(60), so app gone to sleep for 1 minute(during which alarm have triggered alert), and then i am checking alert by using your code,

Comment: you mean when app is awake again then alert is already on the screen and you fire the above method but didn't work?

Comment: It is not giving me answer.., i dont have downvoted you, someone other has downvoted you, It is always printing UILayoutContainerView, i am upvoting you, i dont want to make you unsatisfied

Comment: @MDThakkar: I've tested the code. It's working here. What I've done is: First I've show `UIAlertView` and then after 1 second I fired above method, and it returns `true` with log `UIAlertView` !!!